# How to kill an infinite loop process in Erlang

Tags: erlang

If I create a module with this code below

```
start_nonstop() ->
  spawn(fun() ->
        Pid = spawn(?MODULE, nonstop, [0]),
        timer:sleep(1000),
        exit(Pid, kill)
    end).

nonstop(N) ->
    io:format("number: ~B~n", [N + 1]),
    nonstop(N + 1).
```

and call `start_nonstop()` from the Erlang shell, I see an endless series of

`number: 1`

`number: 2`

`...`

which means that the `nonstop(N)` process was not killed as expected by calling `exit(Pid,kill)`...

What am I doing wrong? Obviously, this code is a mockup, but I think there is always the chance that some logic bug in a process might result in an infinite loop behaviour similar to this one.

I supposed this could be handled by Erlang, but if not, how can I have an Erlang application be protected regarding these kind of situations?

Which patterns of "infinite loops" can Erlang break? For example, if I put a sleep in the middle of the `nonstop(N)` functions, Erlang can break the infinite loop, but if I put an `erlang:yield()` it still cannot break from the infinite loop ...

In this case the infinite process is local to the one trying to kill it. But, what if the infinite process was in a different (e.g., remote) Erlang VM? Could it be killed then?

I am a newbie, and I am evaluating Erlang before I put too much effort in learning and using it for serious applications.

Thanks

Comment: I am having trouble now with this thread because I am not seeing the answers or comments that other people have already made (which I could see some minutes ago). Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, you spawn two process.
In function `start_nonstop()`, you spawn an process, we can call it `Process1`. Then in `Process1`, you spawn another process, we call it `Process2`.

The work of `Process2` is:

```
nonstop(N) ->
    io:format("number: ~B~n", [N + 1]),
    nonstop(N + 1).
```

just do `io:format("number: ~B~n", [N + 1])`, until the `Process1` kill it.

In my environment, the `Process2` can be killed. But the variable `N` become very large from the output.

```
number: 51321
number: 51322
number: 51323
number: 51324
number: 51325
number: 51326
number: 51327
number: 51328
number: 51329
number: 51330
number: 51331
number: 51332
7>
```

Comment: I now see that Erlang successfully kills Process2. I have made some other tests, and it seems that Process2 is really killed, but since it iterated a lot, the shell keeps writing long after Process2 got killed. Thanks for your efforts.